# Cannot redeclare drupal_get_hash_salt()

Tags: configuration

I had a site and it was running fine on the live server but when I moved it to my local server it gave me this error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare drupal_get_hash_salt() (previously declared in 
D:\wamp\www\htdocs\projects\mysite\includes\bootstrap.inc:2248) in 
D:\wamp\www\htdocs\projects\mysite\includes\common.inc on line 5045
```

I guess the problem occurred because of editing the variable

```
$drupal_hash_salt = 'zU4q79TqFe0thQO-xGQbfbrFfKloUk9OYXfQ70J1nw0';
```

manually in setting.php file.

Does anybody have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but no dice, are you sure that removing that solves the problem? what do you have in that 5045 line of common.inc?

Comment: ON line 5046 I have the function **function drupal_get_hash_salt** as defined [Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_hash_salt/7)

Comment: Just got this on a 7.24 upgrade (I know I am behind...) although it was line html/includes/common.inc on line 5065; this saved me many hours of pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got definitely a Drupal upgrade problem, [drupal_get_hash_salt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_hash_salt/7) used to be in common.inc and was moved to bootstrap.inc in Drupal 7.23 version as you can see in https://www.drupal.org/node/1739986.

Something went wrong with your core update, I'd suggest you to backup your data and upgrade your files to the latest version, then run update.php and check everything is OK.

Comment: As you said "Upgrade your files to the latest version", I searched **Manually update Drupal core** and I find this article **https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290**. I followed all the steps and as soon as I reached to the 3rd last step I saw mysite working. Thank you for putting me in the right direction.